# User Showing in User Manager but not Data base

Tags: user, database

Problem, users are showing in User MGR and they can login, but the users are not showing in the data base.

I've created new database and reinstalled same issue, Tried creating a test user with the new DB the user is created and can log in but the user is not showing up in the database.

I am extremely perplexed by this?

Joomla 3.8.10

Answer (score 1):

Since this can not be happening - most likely your site is using another database than the one you are looking at. Make sure that this isn't the case.

Also, check the case that the tables you are looking at are those with the right prefix. The table you need to check for the users should be `#__users`.

Make also sure you aren't seeing any filtered or special sorted table records.

Double check your configuration for the Database Info. 
You can also change the password for the database user of your databases to test if the site is still operating or not.

Comment: I thought that too, but the other databases not have the other users. I've just created a new test user and that user is not save to any of the databases yet stil I can still use the test user to login front end. The DB info shown in Joomla is the same as the existing DB. I have exported and setup with xampp local server and the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the there a 2 different DB prefixes with the database, not sure where that came from but backup restore to different server reintegrate new prefixes?

Mystery resolved and I have no idea who the DB got so messed up...as mentioned the prefix did not match the DB prefix...strange how it would still work, that is when I discovered that the real prefix was 3 pages back the db had over 500 tables.

sure enough there were the users back in page 3 with the correct prefix. search all the non correct prefixes and dropped the tables. now down to 178 tables woohoo

This would explain why I was getting login error when trying to update from Joomla 3.8.10 to 3.8.11 it was looking at the wrong login info or most likely taking the first one it came across

Crossing finger all appears to working correctly.